# LibreOffice Impress does not preserve hyperlinks on ppt export?

Tags: libreoffice, presentation

I am having a hard time with exporting Impress' presentation (in .odp format ) to .ppt format. The problem is that Impress won't preserve my hyperlinks.

I have found a bug on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/721386 but it's for old version of Impress.

I am using one of the latest 4.2.2.

Any solutions for that ? Does this work for you?